# DSE 3.2 SOLR FileNotFoundException

Tags: solr, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax

Just updated to DSE 3.2 from 3.1 using the guide to run the update, now the logs littered with this exception.  When querying via SOLR we are getting missing data, however it seems that when querying using cqlsh or the cli, the data is there.

```
ERROR [IndexPool work thread-6] 2013-11-18 22:32:18,748 AbstractSolrSecondaryIndex    .java (line 912) _yaqn8_Lucene41_0.tip
java.io.FileNotFoundException: _yaqn8_Lucene41_0.tip
    at org.apache.lucene.store.bytebuffer.ByteBufferDirectory.fileLength(    ByteBufferDirectory.java:129)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.NRTCachingDirectory.sizeInBytes(NRTCachingDirectory    .java:158)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.NRTCachingDirectory.doCacheWrite(    NRTCachingDirectory.java:289)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.NRTCachingDirectory.createOutput(    NRTCachingDirectory.java:199)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.TrackingDirectoryWrapper.createOutput(    TrackingDirectoryWrapper.java:62)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.compressing.CompressingStoredFieldsWriter.<init>(    CompressingStoredFieldsWriter.java:107)
    at com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.index.solr.CassandraStoredFieldsWriter.<init>(    CassandraStoredFieldsWriter.java:25)
    at com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.index.solr.CassandraStoredFieldsFormat.    fieldsWriter(CassandraStoredFieldsFormat.java:39)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.StoredFieldsProcessor.initFieldsWriter(    StoredFieldsProcessor.java:86)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.StoredFieldsProcessor.finishDocument(    StoredFieldsProcessor.java:119)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.TwoStoredFieldsConsumers.finishDocument(    TwoStoredFieldsConsumers.java:65)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DocFieldProcessor.finishDocument(DocFieldProcessor.    java:274)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriterPerThread.updateDocument(    DocumentsWriterPerThread.java:274)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.updateDocument(DocumentsWriter.    java:376)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.updateDocument(IndexWriter.java:1485)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc(DirectUpdateHandler2.    java:201)
    at com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.index.solr.CassandraDirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc(    CassandraDirectUpdateHandler2.java:103)
    at com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.index.solr.AbstractSolrSecondaryIndex.doIndex(    AbstractSolrSecondaryIndex.java:929)
    at com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.index.solr.AbstractSolrSecondaryIndex.    doUpdateOrDelete(AbstractSolrSecondaryIndex.java:586)
    at com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.index.solr.ThriftSolrSecondaryIndex.    updateColumnFamilyIndex(ThriftSolrSecondaryIndex.java:114)
    at com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.index.solr.AbstractSolrSecondaryIndex$3.run(    AbstractSolrSecondaryIndex.java:896)
    at com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.index.solr.concurrent.IndexWorker.run(    IndexWorker.java:38)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.    java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.    java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

alo this:

```
ERROR 22:53:01,426 auto commit error...:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error opening new searcher
    at com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.index.solr.CassandraDirectUpdateHandler2.commit(CassandraDirectUpdateHandler2.java:318)
    at org.apache.solr.update.CommitTracker.run(CommitTracker.java:216)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error opening new searcher
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.openNewSearcher(SolrCore.java:1457)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.getSearcher(SolrCore.java:1569)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.commit(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:557)
    at com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.index.solr.CassandraDirectUpdateHandler2.commit(CassandraDirectUpdateHandler2.java:276)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: _xfgfw_Lucene41_0.tim
    at org.apache.lucene.store.bytebuffer.ByteBufferDirectory.fileLength(ByteBufferDirectory.java:129)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.NRTCachingDirectory.sizeInBytes(NRTCachingDirectory.java:158)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.NRTCachingDirectory.doCacheWrite(NRTCachingDirectory.java:289)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.NRTCachingDirectory.createOutput(NRTCachingDirectory.java:199)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.TrackingDirectoryWrapper.createOutput(TrackingDirectoryWrapper.java:62)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene42.Lucene42FieldInfosWriter.write(Lucene42FieldInfosWriter.java:49)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DocFieldProcessor.flush(DocFieldProcessor.java:88)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriterPerThread.flush(DocumentsWriterPerThread.java:493)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.doFlush(DocumentsWriter.java:422)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.flushAllThreads(DocumentsWriter.java:559)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.getReader(IndexWriter.java:365)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader.doOpenFromWriter(StandardDirectoryReader.java:270)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader.doOpenIfChanged(StandardDirectoryReader.java:255)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader.openIfChanged(DirectoryReader.java:250)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.openNewSearcher(SolrCore.java:1393)
    ... 12 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like some files did not flush correctly on shutdown.  You will have to do a full re-index (with deleting) on nodes showing those errors to get the lucene indexes to rebuild.

This page shows how to initiate a re-index. http://www.datastax.com/docs/datastax_enterprise3.2/solutions/dse_search_upload#reloading-a-solr-core

Comment: how do I do a full re-index with deleting? just with `nodetool rebuild_index my_ks my_cf my_ks.my_cf` ?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure why things didn't flush properly.  I did a `nodetool drain` before restarting each node.

Comment: A full re-index fixed the missing data issues, however we are still getting the exceptions.

Comment: The exceptions should be harmless.  Just annoying in the logs.

Answer (score 5):

This is known issue that is fixed in DSE 3.2.1.

We just released 3.2.1, which should address your issues. Our developers where able to replicate the stack trace, and resolved that. We also addressed the issue with the indexes not properly handled after a restart.

Comment: Well the data is missing when we use the SOLR interface. Does that mean I should have to rebuild?

Comment: Thanks for the info. This is exactly why I asked this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20051932/cassandra-solr-rolling-upgrade

Comment: Just to be clear, what's fixed in DSE 3.2.1 is the throwing of the exception. The missing data is something that warrants separate investigation.

Comment: I see, well i have the full reindexes running now. I'll let you know when they complete if it has fixed or not.

Comment: The re-index fixed the missing data issues, however we are still getting the exceptions.  Are there any side effects to the exceptions?

Answer (score 3):

A workaround for this is to change your solr config to use (we are working on a proper fix):

```
<directoryFactory name="DirectoryFactory" class="solr.StandardDirectoryFactory"/>
```

Comment: Does this require a restart of DSE or a rebuild of the indexes?

Comment: Made this change and still seeing the exceptions, haven't restarted or reindexed, is that required?

Comment: ok tries restarting and it screwed the indexes again.  now having to rebuild.

Comment: After this change, we restarted and the index on that node became corrupt.  We had to rebuild the index.  Is this going to happen on every restart?

Comment: That is unexpected, I will have to check with the developers. After rebuilding, do you still see exceptions or inconsistent data?

Comment: it's still rebuilding, we will let you know.

Comment: ok after the rebuild of the indexes, I am still seeing errors in the log.

Comment: That's the same stack traces as before (which one), and with the changed DirectoryFacotry?

Comment: Yes, we changed the directory factory and are having the same stack traces as before.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem continues, then the CF needs to be re-indexed.